# Can unit tests be used for checking student work

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class of high school programming students and I would like an automated way to check the validity of their work. I go through their code and look for structure, efficiency and basic expected outcomes but I was hoping to take it to another level.

Would Unit Testing be a viable solution? 
Is there an elegant way of check a bunch of student programs at once?

We are using Eclipse and I've imported their project, containing all of their programs, from their local network drive. Works great. I'm just trying to give them more feedback on how they are doing, and even introduce them to unit testing, which is something I've never done.

Comment: If you are asking for code, please show us what you have tried so far and ask more specific questions. I can tell you it is possible, but there are many many ways to do so. In the current state of the question, it may be more suitable for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21120003/829571

Comment: @assylias Thanks for the link. It looks like this is for test methods. We are not using methods yet. It also seems that you need to have all the students' methods in one class and then it would go through and check them all. That would take too much time for some programs. I'll have to look at it some more later.

Comment: The example assumed one class per student so you basically copy paste all the classes you receive in one folder, collect the names of the classes and run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

yes sure you can do that for checking the students work as

```
Unit Testing reduces the level of bugs in production code. 
Automated tests can be run as frequently as required.
```

Comment: "Automated tests can be run as frequently as required." How?

Comment: @tazboy If u make the Automated Test Suite then u can run it on daily basis without require much effort my friend

Comment: How do I make these automated tests?

Answer (score 0):

In my university we had automated tests for excercises. We just mailed the class files or built jars to an email address. On the serverside you set them in the classpath and start your tests. It's actually quite easy to implement. The important thing is to clearly document package structure and such in the given requirements, maybe even supply a project skeleton.

Nice plus: the students were given a smaller sets of tests so they could verify they work before they submitted it.

Comment: I thought I heard about serverside tests. Seems like a great idea. I don't know how to do that though. You say that it's quite easy, do you have any resources for me?

Comment: Well I guess you could handle this all with existing tools. Poll the mail server, parse the subject to identify the exam, copy the attachment to a temp folder and run your tests with the right classpath. Send an answer depending on success or failure. Does not need much programming, just a bit commandline fu. Could be done solely in java with a few hundred lines of code, too. Depends on your skills what suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

I think introducing them to unit testing and TDD is a great idea.

However, if YOU write the unit tests and give them to your students before they do the assignment, then they won't learn to write unit tests. Also, they will structure their code according to your test, which may or may not be what you want.

If they, on the other hand, write the unit tests, they will learn how to do that, but you won't know what their tests are testing.

Perhaps you could extract code test coverage and assign them to reach 80, 90 or 100% coverage or something like that.

I did a review of a programming test today, for a eventual new hire, and I feel that the reasoning behind programming choices is really important.

Comment: Code coverage is not necessary a good test quality criterion and should not be used as single goal.

Comment: I agree. That's why I wrote that the reasoning behind programming choices is important. Also, he is looking for a cheap way to give more feedback and is considering unit tests. Coverage could be one component in the feedback.

Comment: I have never done unit testing myself but I feel it's an integral part of programming. So it's sad that I don't know about it. By the way you phrased your statements it seems that unit tests are coded within the class. In that case I see where you are coming from. And I have no idea what code coverage is. Geez.